# Continuing a javascript after using .click() on a button which adds new DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am a lowly operations employee without authorization to change the programs and permissions on my machine, and I would like to automate some highly repetitive data entry. I know there are a lot of programs that can do that, however, for the sake of this discussion we'll assume that I'm not allowed to have any of them and I can only script through the debug F12 menu in Chrome. I also probably don't understand half of these words as well as I should.

I have to run test cases on a third-party vendor's highly dynamic website, and I've already successfully written javascript which adds texts to elements in the DOM and presses the "next" button.

**The problem is**, upon `.click()`ing the "next" button, it takes time for the page to update, and the update creates new elements which weren't in the DOM when the script was initialized. I need to find a way to delay the execution of the script until the DOM contains all the elements I need to update.

As a really, really crude proof of concept I wrote the pre-filler for each page as a function, and I serially called each function at the end of the previous function, using `setTimeout(nextfunct, 10000)` to let the page update before executing the next line. (I was going to refine that by trying to create some kind of object listener instead of an arbitrary 10 second delay, but I wasn't even able to get that far.) This approach creates two errors.

1) The script seems to be checking whether the elements are on the DOM before the end of the `setTimeout()`, so it still gives me an error. If `nextfunct` is defined as

```
document.getElementById("doesntexistyet").value = "Fill Me";
console.log("nextfunct ran");
```

I will get the error message stating there is no element with the id `"doesntexistyet`" immediately, not after a delay of 10 seconds. The element on the next page will not update.

2) The DOM updating interrupts my script. In the above code, the console output will not ever appear in my console. If I comment out the missing element, so the function only prints a comment, it will still not appear in my console. However, if I comment out the code and I switch the `setTimeout` to 1ms, `"nextfunct ran"` will appear in my console, until the page updates, at which time the console will be deleted.

Are there ways around this which I can implement using only vanilla JS and a browser? I'm sure there's a keyword I can search for where someone has discussed this before, but it seems like the vast majority of JS autofilling discussions are oriented towards people designing code to be integrated into a website,

Thanks

Comment: `The DOM updating interrupts my script. In the above code, the console output will not ever appear in my console.` It sounds like the *entire page* is being replaced (eg navigation to a new URL) if the previous Javascript in a timeout no longer runs, is this the case?

Comment: The URL is the same, although it ends in .aspx and I'm not sure how that'll impact things.

Comment: The page can be replaced even if the URL is the same, can you check whether that's happening?

Comment: Certainly, but that's a new concept for me. What's the best way to see?

Comment: eg, open the console, type something in and press enter, then wait until the UI changes. If the message you typed before is gone, the page has been replaced.

Comment: Since you seem to be able to change Chrome locally, would you be open to a solution that uses a custom Chrome extension? That way you could get around the issue @CertainPerformance is describing

Comment: Ah. Yes, it's replacing the page. That probably ends that then.

Comment: Yep, can you install Chrome extensions?

Comment: Matthew,

I will investigate that route.

Comment: I do not appear to be able to load an unpacked extension. Almost certainly this is a sysadmin rule.